# SAPUI5 application failing to load from resources/WebContent/myapp/demo.view.js

Tags: sapui5

I am trying to create a simple Hello World application with SAPUI5. Using Eclipse 2020-12 IDE, I right-click on index.html file, then click *Run As -> Web App Preview* to view the application. When I tried to view the application on a browser, I get following error on console:

> Uncaught Error: failed to load 'WebContent/myapp/demo.view.js' from resources/WebContent/myapp/demo.view.js: 404 - Not Found

The code for the relevant files are as follows:

**/myApp/src/main/webapp/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html;charset=UTF-8'/>

        <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
                data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal">
        </script>
        <!-- only load the mobile lib "sap.m" and the "sap_bluecrystal" theme -->

        <script>
                sap.ui.localResources("myapp");
                var app = new sap.m.App({initialPage:"iddemo1"});
                var page = sap.ui.view({id:"iddemo1", viewName:"WebContent.myapp.demo", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
                app.addPage(page);
                app.placeAt("content");
        </script>

    </head>
    <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**/myApp/WebContent/myapp/demo.view.js**

```
sap.ui.jsview("WebContent.myapp.demo", {

    /** Specifies the Controller belonging to this View. 
    * In the case that it is not implemented, or that "null" is returned, this View does not have a Controller.
    * @memberOf WebContent.myapp.demo
    */ 
    getControllerName : function() {
        return "WebContent.myapp.demo";
    },

    /** Is initially called once after the Controller has been instantiated. It is the place where the UI is constructed. 
    * Since the Controller is given to this method, its event handlers can be attached right away. 
    * @memberOf WebContent.myapp.demo
    */ 
    createContent : function(oController) {
        return new sap.m.Page({
            title: "Hello World",
            content: [
            
            ]
        });
    }

});
```

**/myApp/WebContent/myapp/demo.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.controller("WebContent.myapp.demo", {

/**
* Called when a controller is instantiated and its View controls (if available) are already created.
* Can be used to modify the View before it is displayed, to bind event handlers and do other one-time initialization.
* @memberOf WebContent.myapp.demo
*/
//  onInit: function() {
//
//  },

/**
* Similar to onAfterRendering, but this hook is invoked before the controller's View is re-rendered
* (NOT before the first rendering! onInit() is used for that one!).
* @memberOf WebContent.myapp.demo
*/
//  onBeforeRendering: function() {
//
//  },

/**
* Called when the View has been rendered (so its HTML is part of the document). Post-rendering manipulations of the HTML could be done here.
* This hook is the same one that SAPUI5 controls get after being rendered.
* @memberOf WebContent.myapp.demo
*/
//  onAfterRendering: function() {
//
//  },

/**
* Called when the Controller is destroyed. Use this one to free resources and finalize activities.
* @memberOf WebContent.myapp.demo
*/
//  onExit: function() {
//
//  }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the application using UI5 Tooling (https://sap.github.io/ui5-tooling/)? I would recommend using this -- it will definitely allow you to easily run your UI5 applications.
UI5 Tooling will allow you to initialize (`ui5 init`) a project and to run the application (`ui5 serve`).

Comment: No, I haven't tried using UI5 Tooling

Answer (score 0):

The plugin "SAPUI5 Tools for Eclipse" is no longer maintained and doesn't support Eclipse higher than **2019-12**. In case you're using it, please don't. See [*SAPUI5 Tools for Eclipse – Now is the Time to Look for Alternatives*](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/11/26/sapui5-tools-for-eclipse-now-is-the-time-to-look-for-alternatives/).

Alternatives are mentioned at the documentation topic [*Development Environment*](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/7bb04e05f9484e1b95b38a2e48ecef4f). Consider starting from https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/8b49fc198bf04b2d9800fc37fecbb218 instead of outdated tutorials that still use Eclipse.